# Where to add "make install" in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Does it make a difference (and if so, what difference) where I add the `make install` step?

In some posts they say to add it under `Build` like in the first screenshot. Others say it needs to go under `Run/Deployment` like in the 2nd.

Are both ways equivalent?

[image: Install under build]
[image: Install under Deployment]

Comment: Why do you want to run make install as part of QtC nuild/run?

Comment: It is a special case, normally it is not needed. In that particular case it is required to copy files into a 3rd party directory for a plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is part of Build Settings, it will be done every time you do a build under Qt Creator (assuming previous steps succeeded).

If it is part of Run Settings, it will only be run when you actually run the app under Qt Creator.

It depends on the case, which on you want. If it is part of Run Settings, then logically it should be configured to run the installed/deployed binary. If it is just for checking that `make install` succeeds, as part of the build, even though it will run the application from build directory when you run it under Qt Creator, then it should be part of build.

In your case, it sounds like `make install` is needed for running the app, so maybe it could be part of Run settings, to make normal builds just a bit faster.

Comment: It is a special case, normally it is not needed. In that particular case it is required to copy files into a 3rd party directory for a plugin.